# Display the image rotated in KIVY

Tags: python, rotation, kivy, transformation

I want to display an image in kivy but rotated to 270 degrees (only preview, not file) is there any way to do this **without kivy file**.

This is my code relating to the image:

```
self.rawimageshow = Image(source="C:/testing/" + (rawimagename))
self.rawimageshow.reload()
fl.add_widget(self.rawimageshow)
return fl
```

Comment: You can do anything without a kv file. In this case you want to use a Rotate instruction, or more simply you can change the tex_coords used to display the image.

Comment: @inclement I tried to do it but I can't figure it out. Can you please send me the code I need to add? Thank You!